# Request for a suggestion a user friendly programming editor for ONE Simulator?

Tags: windows, editor, one-simulator

currently, I'm into coding a routing protocol in ONE Simulator. Any suggestion for programming editor software for coding purposes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally I used Eclipse. But probably today I’d go for VScode.